# Can I "clone" Hyper-V VM's to a physical hard drive then use it in a real PC?

Tags: hyper-v, cloning

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V.

Can I create a Virtual Machine, install Ubuntu 11.10, then "clone" it to a real physical hard drive for use as a real OS in a physical PC?

Comment: I don't know the 'official' way to do this with Hyper-V but cloning a Linux box is as simple as copying the files (except /dev/* /proc/* and /sys/*), chrooting in it and reinstalling grub.  I guess you could use a tool like clonezilla to clone your VM, then restore it on a physical drive.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about Ubuntu, not Hyper-V.  How is it you move an Ubuntu image from one physical machine to another?  That same answer will apply here.

Comment: Correct. There may be some magic (and presumably expensive) tool designed to do this, but I doubt that SCVMM is going to be much help when you're running Ubuntu. I'd just clone it like it's a physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried going from V2P...But Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager (SCVMM) might be able to do it.  Though Ubuntu isn't one of the supported languages it may do what you need.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/virtual-machine-manager.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Shut down your Hyper-V server (unless you can hot-plug the new disk).
2. Connect the new physical disk to the Hyper-V server.
3. In Server Manager -> Disk Management, set this new physical disk to Offline.
4. Add a new SCSI disk to your virtual machine in Hyper-V Manager and point it to the physical disk that you just took offline.
5. Set the virtual machine's CD drive to point to an Ubuntu LiveCD image. The installation disc ISO will work fine.
6. Fire up the virtual machine and boot from the LiveCD.
7. Use `dd if=/dev/<virtualdisk> of=/dev/<physicaldisk>` (substituting whatever device names they actually have) to copy the image to the physical disk.
8. Shut everything down.
9. Install the physical disk in the actual PC.
10. Boot the PC.

As long as the kernel, drivers, partitioning scheme, etc. are compatible with the physical PC and the image fits on the disk, you should be fine.